# Modern CMake - dependency propagation

Tags: cmake

We have following folder structure, agree its a bit weird but it is what it is

```
LIB
   Cmakelist1
Project
   MainProject
     CMakeList2
     SubProject1
       CMakeList3
     SubProject2
       CmakeList4
```

Question 1: `Cmakelist2` contains the following:

```
add_subdirectory(LIB/CMakelist1)
```

Is this acceptable or is there a better way of doing it in modern CMake style?
This is resolved looks fine.

Question 2: `Cmakelist1` builds static libs using `target_link_libraries`/`target_include_directory` constructs.

When building executable Subproject1, I include LIB1 as

```
add_executable( SUBPROJECT1 )
target_link_libraries(SUBPROJECT1 PRIVATE LIB1)
```

When I compile SubProject1, I am getting compilation errors for include directories of boost/xyz and abc. Which I included in LIB1 as PUBLIC include header like

```
target_include_directory(LIB1 
     PUBLIC lib/include
     PUBLIC boost/include
     PUBLIC XYZ/include
     PUBLIC abc/include
```

Am I supposed to include includes and linked libraries of LIB1 again if they are been referenced by SUBPROJECT1 ?

Example:
LIB/CMakeList1:

```
add_library(lib1 STATIC)
target_include_directory(lib1 
     PUBLIC lib/include
     PUBLIC boost/include
     PUBLIC XYZ/include
     PUBLIC abc/include
)
target_link_libraries(lib1 PUBLIC boost/lib1 xyz.a abc.so)
```

MainProject/CMakeList2:

```
add_subdirectory(../LIB1) #this works fine relative path is just for reference
add_subdirectory(subproject1)
add_subdirectory(subproject2)
```

SubProject1/CMakeList3

```
add_executable( Proj1 )
target_sources( Proj1 x.cpp y.cpp z.cpp ) # these file have link to Lib1/xyz ->x1.h/y1.h etc

target_link_libraries( Proj1 PRIVATE lib1 )
```

I do not want to call `target_link_libraries` for `boost/xyz` and `abc`.
Question 3: do i need to explicitly add `target_link_directory` for `boost/xyz` and `abc` again in `SubProject1`.

Comment: I don't understand. The code presented should work right as it is. What exactly are you having problem with? Q1: It's ok. Q2: You can, but you don't(?), you just link against the library with target_link_libraries(... lib1) exactly like you do. Q3: No, this is exactly what inheriting transitive dependencies in cmake is for.

Comment: During compilation even though i hav linked xyx and abc in LIB 1, I have to include header files and linked libraries of LIB1 in executable {subproject1}.

Comment: Good, just do it then. Does it work? What do you think that `PRIVATE` `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` in `target_link_libraries` _and_ `target_include_directories` is for? As to `this works fine relative path is just for reference` - just pass two arguments like `add_subdirectory(../LIB1 LIB1)` - the second is the name inside CMAKE_BINARY_DIR to put the compilation results in. If it does not work, try passing absolute paths, like `target_include_directories(.... ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/include)`.

Comment: If I have included a set of headers and libraries in a static lib, do we need to include it again in executable using target_include_*. From the literature on cmake it appeared like it should propagate seamlessly.

Comment: Are boost/lib1, xyz and abc built using their own targets in CMake?

Comment: You don't need to do that, that is exactly what inheriting [INTERFACE_INLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) target property is for. Maybe, if, `abc.a` is a static library and `abc.so` is a shared library, it might be preferred to use `add_library(... IMPORTED)` to import those.

Comment: No boost, xyz and abc are already built not building it locally

Comment: @KamilCuk : exactly my point, what seems to be missing in that case. Do I need to use INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ?

Comment: Then I think that is the problem. Since lib1 is a static library it won't do any linking by its own. And since boost, xyz and abc are prebuilt the transitive mechanism of CMake will not work.

Comment: @arghol : lib1 which is static lib links to boost/xyz and abc. Does that mean static libs dependencies are not transitive. What every i have linked to lib1, include headers and libs I am expecting only those to be propagated

Comment: I am not entirely sure about this, but I think that boost/xyz and abc need to be proper CMake targets themself in order to be transitive. Maybe you can do a minimal test.

Comment: @amit: Please, update your question post with information what **exactly** you are doing and **exact problem** (e.g error message). In the current form you question cannot be answered, because it is very unclear what is your problem. See also [ask].